# Issue with CONCAT() mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `table`  and i am running a `query` and fetching full name from table like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(f_name ,  " - ",  l_name )  as fullname FROM  user
```

It wokrs fine but when i have no value in `l_name` which is `null` by default

It doesn't give `f_name` instead it gives me `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CONCAT_WS:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', f_name,  l_name)  as fullname FROM  user
```

concat will return null if a value is null, concat_ws will just skip null values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it returns null if any of the variables are null.

You can have a check using `if` in `mysql`, if any of the values is null return `''` else the actual value

```
 SELECT CONCAT(if(f_name is null,'',f_name ) , 
   if(f_name is not null and l_name is not null, " - ",""), 
   if(l_name is null,'',l_name ) )  
 as fullname FROM  user
```

You will need  a check to cater `-` in your query. It should appear only and only if none of the values is `null`.

Comment: @Jens added check for both the columns

Comment: when last name is null, the value becomes null. I am using if to validate NULL. concat_ws is smart approach though

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression.
Check whether `l_name` column is null and it contains only white space.
If so avoid adding `-` character and `l_name` along with `f_name`.
Otherwise add `-` and `l_name` with `f_name`.

**Query**

```
select concat(f_name,(
    case when l_name is null or length(trim(l_name)) = 0 then '' 
    else concat('-', l_name) end)
) as fullname
from user;
```

Comment: But this Returns f_name - not only f_name

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT concat(f_name ,  if(l_name is null,'',concat("-", l_name) ) ) fullname 
FROM  user
```